# How to compare non 'Eq' type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

When loading the following module I get the error:

> No instance for (Eq Planet) arising from a use of ‘==’
> • In the expression: planet == Mercury
> In a stmt of a pattern guard for
> an equation for ‘ageOn’:

How can I check whether planet equals a certain planet?

```
module SpaceAge (Planet(..), ageOn) where

data Planet = Mercury
        | Venus
        | Earth
        | Mars
        | Jupiter
        | Saturn
        | Uranus
        | Neptune

mercury :: Float
mercury = 0.2408467

venus :: Float
venus = 0.61519726

earth :: Float
earth = 1.0

mars :: Float
mars = 1.8808158

jupiter :: Float
jupiter = 11.862615

saturn :: Float
saturn = 29.447498

uranus :: Float
uranus = 84.016846

neptune :: Float
neptune = 164.79132

ageOn :: Planet -> Float -> Float
ageOn planet seconds
   | planet == Mercury = seconds * mercury
   | planet == Venus = seconds * venus
   | planet == Earth = seconds * earth
   | planet == Mars = seconds * mars
   | planet == Jupiter = seconds * jupiter
   | planet == Saturn = seconds * saturn
   | planet == Uranus = seconds * uranus
   | planet == Neptune = seconds * neptune
```

Comment: Use pattern matching. Or you could always add `deriving Eq` to the datatype definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with *pattern matching*:

```
ageOn :: Planet -> Float -> Float
ageOn Mercury seconds = seconds * mercury
ageOn Venus seconds = seconds * venus
ageOn Earth seconds = seconds * earth
ageOn Mars seconds = seconds * mars
ageOn Jupiter seconds = seconds * jupiter
ageOn Saturn seconds = seconds * saturn
ageOn Uranus seconds = seconds * uranus
ageOn Neptune seconds = seconds * neptune
```

But you can also make `Planet` an instance of the `Eq` typeclass. If you simply want to check if two `Planet`s are the same if you use the same data constructor, you can let Haskell implement this with a `deriving` clause:

```
data Planet
  = Mercury
  | Venus
  | Earth
  | Mars
  | Jupiter
  | Saturn
  | Uranus
  | Neptune
  deriving Eq
```

Comment: pattern matching is the "cleaner" way, i.e. experienced Haskell coders would use that instead of the deriving clause, right?

Comment: @timtam: well the two are not equivalent. You could make an instance of `Eq` where for example `Mercury` and `Venus` are equal, whereas for pattern matching you match it with the data constructor, and you can "unpack" the parameters (here there are no parameters).

Comment: @timtam Implementing your `ageOn` with pattern matching is indeed cleaner. You'd typically *also* want to have the `Eq` instance, as it can be useful in other situations (arbitrary examples: [`group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) and [`elem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elem) have an `Eq` constraint on the list elements).

Comment: @timtam FWIW I have a different opinion than duplode: I would 100% derive `Eq` -- and also `Ord` and `Enum`. Then I'd make a `Map Planet Double` with something like `myPlanetMap = M.fromList (zip [Mercury .. Neptune] [mercury, venus, earth, {- ... -}, neptune])`, and write `ageOn planet seconds = (myPlanetMap ! planet) * seconds`.

Comment: @timtam When writing a function that processes a **known** type by checking different cases, experienced Haskellers will typically use pattern matching. `Eq` checking is more usually used by generic functions that don't know what type they're dealing with (so they can't pattern match on a statically compiled set of cases, but may need to check against other values they have access to). That is exactly why @DanielWagner's suggestion needs `Eq` (and `Ord`); it's reusing generic functionality for `Map` that works with any type that has an `Ord` instance, rather than specific to your `Planet`.

Answer (score 2):

```hs
ageOn planet seconds = seconds * case planet of
  Mercury -> mercury
  Venus -> venus
  Earth -> earth
  Mars -> mars
  ...
```

Or better yet, factor out the looking up.

```hs
yearLength :: Planet -> Float
yearLength = \case
  Mercury -> mercury
  Venus -> venus
  ...

ageOn planet seconds = yearLength planet * seconds
```

At the same time, I think you might have an error in your logic. If I've lived for 1 Earth year, I've lived for more than 1 Mercury year. So depending on exactly what your function means, you probably want to define

```hs
ageOn planet earthYears = earthYears / yearLength planet
```